# Why can I connect to PostgreSQL server with PgAdmin from outside network, but not within it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL server set up on Ubuntu on a computer connected to my home WiFi. I also have a Windows machine with pgAdmin set up to connect to this server. However, I found that the windows machine is only able to connect to the PostgreSQL server when it's on a *different* network from my home wifi. When I try to connect to the server from the same wifi network, I get "server doesn't listen." Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just to clarify is the database server Microsoft [tag:sql-server] or [tag:postgresql]?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql. Just edited the question description to reflect this.

Comment: you'll have to edit the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files

Comment: I did that already. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to connect at all.

Comment: Are you trying to connect using its internal or external address?

Comment: Maybe is a stupid question but sometimes it has been forgotten, have you restarted the server after modifying the files?

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen: external address

xCloudx8: Yep